# Can Load Balancer be only responsible for TCP handshake and selecting appropriate workers?

Tags: tcp, server, load-balancing

Can Load Balancer be only responsible for TCP handshake and selecting appropriate workers and next network flows are transferred between client and worker?I searched lots of information about Load Balance , like LVS , but seems that  IP Tunneling and Direct Routing Mode can only be used for achieving the following purpose:

- The response data can be directly send from worker to client.
- The request data is still relayed by load balancer which means that the request data is passed from client to Load Balancer to Worker..

What I want to achieve is as follows:

[image]

- Client sends request to Load Balancer.
- Load Balancer assigns a proper worker to Client.
- Then next Client and worker communicate directly but not going through the load balancer.

The next steps may work ,but I think it is a little stupid..

- Client sends request to Load Balancer.
- Load Balancer response the proper worker's IP to client.
- Client disconnect from Load Balancer and establish a TCP Connection to Worker directly.
- Then next Client and worker can communicate as expected.

Does anyone have other better ideas?